# Difference between adding Duration.ofDays(1) and Period.ofDays(1) to ZonedDateTime around Daylight Savings Time

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, dst, zoneddatetime

The Daylight Savings Time ends on Nov 1 at 2 AM in US/Eastern time zone. As a result, 2 AM becomes 1 AM.

I am not able to understand the following in the code given below:

1. Why line 2 shows time 09:00, why not 10:00 (by adding 1 day)?
2. Why line 4 shows time 10:00, why not 09:00 (by adding 24 hours)?

   ```
   LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.OCTOBER, 31, 10, 0);

   ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.of(ld, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
   System.out.println(date);       //line 1 - 2015-10-31T10:00-04:00[US/Eastern]

   date = date.plus(Duration.ofDays(1));
   System.out.println(date);       //line 2 - 2015-11-01T09:00-05:00[US/Eastern]

   date = ZonedDateTime.of(ld, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
   System.out.println(date);       //line 3 - 2015-10-31T10:00-04:00[US/Eastern]

   date = date.plus(Period.ofDays(1));
   System.out.println(date);       //line 4 - 2015-11-01T10:00-05:00[US/Eastern]
   ```

Could somebody please help me with it?

Comment: 1 day and 24 hours are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Duration:** Despite the `ofDays` method `Duration` hasn’t got a notion of days. `Duration.ofDays(1)` is immediately converted into 24 hours, so this is what you are adding. Since you add 24 hours to 10:00 the day before DST ends, you get 09:00 the next day as you have observed,

**Period:** Contrary to `Duration` a `Period` knows days, weeks, months and years. So you are adding 1 calendar day, hitting the same wall clock time on the next day (10:00) even though this means 25 hours later (not 24).

Comment: If duration adds 24 hours, should it not give 09:00 next day (considering DST)? Similarly, should adding a day (for period of 1 day) give us 10:00 next day? What I am getting in the answer is other way round. `Duration.ofDays(1)` is giving 10:00, while `Period.ofDays(1)` is giving 09:00.

Comment: Aren’t you confusing yourself now? *If duration adds 24 hours, should it not give 09:00 next day (considering DST)?* Yes, and this is also what you report in the question that you get. *Similarly, should adding a day (for period of 1 day) give us 10:00 next day?* Yes, and your question states that this is exactly what you got.

Comment: You're correct. It looks like I've been seeing and reading `Period.ofDays(1)` as `Duration.ofDays(1)` and `Duration.ofDays(1)` as `Period.ofDays(1)`. Even in my question I did the same. I thought `line 2` was for `Period` and `line 4` for `Duration`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

See the full Java documentation on [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html), always one quick Google search away.

From Duration:

> In addition, the DAYS unit can be used and is treated as exactly equal
>   to 24 hours, thus ignoring daylight savings effects. See Period for
>   the date-based equivalent to this class.

From Period:

> Durations and periods differ in their treatment of daylight savings
>   time when added to ZonedDateTime. A Duration will add an exact number
>   of seconds, thus a duration of one day is always exactly 24 hours. By
>   contrast, a Period will add a conceptual day, trying to maintain the
>   local time

So, `Period` will maintain the same hour, whereas Duration will add 24 hours.

24 hours after 10:00 on October 31 is 9:00 on November 1st.

1. 11:00
2. 12:00
3. 13:00 (1 pm)
4. 14:00
5. 15:00
6. 16:00
7. 17:00
8. 18:00
9. 19:00
10. 20:00
11. 21:00
12. 22:00
13. 23:00
14. 0:00 (midnight)
15. 1:00
16. 1:00 (here's that extra hour)
17. 2:00
18. 3:00
19. 4:00
20. 5:00
21. 6:00
22. 7:00
23. 8:00
24. 9:00